# NHibernate multi table query returning same row more than once

Tags: nhibernate

The following nhibernate query is causing me issues because it returns the same row more that once as the child tables have more than one row that match the criteria supplied. What i would like to know is the most efficient/ best practice in nhibernate to do this same query but to only get each row in  DataMappingBase once.  Returning multiple of the same row is breaking my number of results returned as i try to limit it 25 but sometimes i get the same row 25 times.

```
MappedID id = null;
DataMappingBase mapBase = null;
NameDetails name = null;
dmbs = mappingSession.QueryOver<DataMappingBase>(() => mapBase)
   .JoinAlias(() => mapBase.IDs, () => id).WhereRestrictionOn(() => id.SecondaryDataIDType).IsNull()
   .JoinAlias(() => mapBase.Names, () => name).WhereRestrictionOn(() => name.Name).IsInsensitiveLike(request.Filter, MatchMode.Anywhere)
   .Take(request.MaxResults)
   .List();
```

i am currently looking at converting the query above to a detached query and removing the "take" clause and getting it to just return the ID of the matching rows and have it used in a sub-query selecting from "DataMappingBase" where the rows ID is in the ids returned by the sub-query but i am not sure if that is the best way or not.

Comment: Are you using an ISession or an IStatelessSession ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but you can do like this:

```
MappedID id = null;
DataMappingBase mapBase = null;
NameDetails name = null;
dmbs = mappingSession.QueryOver<DataMappingBase>(() => mapBase)
   .JoinAlias(() => mapBase.IDs, () => id).WhereRestrictionOn(() => id.SecondaryDataIDType).IsNull()
   .JoinAlias(() => mapBase.Names, () => name).WhereRestrictionOn(() => name.Name).IsInsensitiveLike(request.Filter, MatchMode.Anywhere)
   .Take(request.MaxResults)
   // add this
   .TransformUsing(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity)
   .List();
```

Comment: Thanks any idea if that would be more efficient than using a subquery? The subquery i was talking about above does work but since i expect to have this issue in other queries that run frequently i am hoping to go with the more efficient option/best practice.

Comment: As usually queries with join more efficient than subquery and i think it's better to use.

Comment: Thanks i will update my code tonight. Thanks for the quick detailed answer

Comment: I think this may be even better http://www.philliphaydon.com/2011/01/revisiting-exists-in-nhibernate-3-0-and-queryover/ The reason i think that is that my understanding is that distinct requires collecting all the results then working out the distinct ones which is very slow in comparison of just selecting the relevant top x rows in the first place. (been talking to DBAs at work to find out what is better from a sql side and mapping that to nhibernate as best i can)